# How to generate first IN and last OUT from attendance log

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an existing attendance log and i want to get the first IN and last OUT of every employee based on date, what can be the query?

already tried using the MAX() and MIN() functions

Sample data below

```
username              date    time
----------------------------------------
user1                07-01-2019 7:20:00
user1                07-01-2019 7:25:00
user2                07-01-2019 7:40:00
user2                07-01-2019 7:42:00
user3                07-01-2019 7:45:00
user3                07-01-2019 7:47:00
user1                07-01-2019 12:00:00
user1                07-01-2019 12:15:00
user2                07-01-2019 12:15:00
user2                07-01-2019 12:40:00
user3                07-01-2019 12:20:00
user3                07-01-2019 12:25:00
user1                07-03-2019 7:20:00
user1                07-03-2019 7:25:00
user2                07-03-2019 7:40:00
user2                07-03-2019 7:42:00
user3                07-03-2019 7:45:00
user3                07-03-2019 7:47:00
user1                07-03-2019 12:00:00
user1                07-03-2019 12:15:00
user2                07-03-2019 12:15:00
user2                07-03-2019 12:40:00
user3                07-03-2019 12:20:00
user3                07-03-2019 12:25:00
```

select [user name] , concat([date],' ',[time]) as inout from test where [user name] != '' order by inout asc
 select [user name] , concat([date],' ',[time]) as inout from test order by inout desc

I expect the output below

```
username                    date    timeIn          timeOut
--------------------------------------------------------------
user1                      07-01-2019 7:20:00       12:15:00
user2                      07-01-2019 7:40:00       12:40:00
user3                      07-01-2019 7:45:00       12:25:00
user1                      07-03-2019 7:20:00       12:00:00
user2                      07-03-2019 7:40:00       12:40:00
user3                      07-03-2019 7:45:00       12:25:00
```

Comment: What was the outcome when you used `MAX()` and `MIN()` functions? Why did this not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try (not tested)

```
SELECT
    username,
    date,
    MIN(time) AS timeIn,
    MAX(time) AS timeOut
FROM
   test
GROUP BY
    username,
    date
ORDER BY
    username,
    date
```

Assumes that you want time in and time out for the same date.